# How to translate my webpage to other language by completely offline using php codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have my completed php codeigniter project which totally runs offline. Due to my customer request I want to translate the view content. Is there any way to translate by offline.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to work with language files in codeigniter

Using CodeIgniter’s Language class, you can easily make your site multi-language.Create multiple language files and insert those files into the application/language/ directory with separate sub-directories for each language (for example, french, german, etc.).

here is a very good tutorial for the same 
http://www.codexworld.com/multi-language-implementation-in-codeigniter/

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial, much helpful